# A property doesn't appear in Winforms PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, propertygrid

I have a property in my custom `Devexpress` `WinForms` component, it is declared in this way:

```
public class MyRepositoryItem : Devexpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem
{
.....
            [Browsable(true)]
            [EditorAttribute(typeof(SearchComboTypeEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
            public Type SearchCombo { get; set; }
....
}
```

The problem is that I don't see the property in winforms PropertyGrid. If I change the property type form `Type` to some custom class I get it in the PropertyGrid. Is the `Type` type some special case and it's impossible to see it in the PropertyGrid?

Here is an example of VS2012 WinForms project with the issue https://yadi.sk/d/PwMlyI07sxvUe

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx

Comment: @MethodMan i've already read this source. Could you please give more precise direction?

Comment: @IlyaMaskov Apprently something is wrong with your `SearchComboTypeEditor` class not shown here. Comment the `EditorAttribute` line and the property should show in the property grid.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've already tried to do that, It doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I've just tried it in a new clean winforms project and it works:) How should we proceed? May be posting a [mcve]?

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok, i've found that it depends on property host base class. It works for example on `System.ComponentModel.Component` child host class and doesn't work on `Devexpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem` child class.

Comment: i put an example project

Comment: RepositoryItem implements the ICustomTypeDescriptor interface with which it can do whatever it want to play dynamically with the property grid (add property, remove property, etc.). This issue is very specific to RepositoryItem and may in fact be by design, you should contact devexpress about this.

Comment: @SimonMourier It looks like you are right. If you post the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, it was more the start of an answer, if you have the final word, everyone can be interested, you should answer yourself and mark as accepted :-)